# NGRX action Typescript error TypeError: Cannot read property 'A_' of undefined at Ps.get

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-effects

So I got this error couple of times now. when trying to pass array of specific type objects to actions in ngrx store from ngrx effects. In my case I want to pass `AngularFireUploadTask[]` to my action. Previosly I had the same error with `User` Products is defined in my project. the way I got rid of the issue was to cast the object to products in effect using (`as User`). the same doesn't seem to work here.

Please help me out understand this issue. the error doesn't give much info.
This is my action:

```
 export const loadUploadSuccess = createAction(
  '[Upload/API] Load Upload Success',
  props<{ upload: AngularFireUploadTask[] }>()
);
```

This is effect:

```
init$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(UploadActions.init),
      fetch({
        run: (action) => {
          const uploads: AngularFireUploadTask[] = [];
          action.files.forEach((file) => {
            uploads.push(this.firebaseStorage.startUpload(file));
          });
          console.log(uploads);
          return UploadActions.loadUploadSuccess({upload: uploads});
        },
        onError: (action, error) => {
          console.error('Error', error);
          return UploadActions.loadUploadFailure({ error });
        },
      })
    )
  );
```

And I will include reducer just in case.

```
  on(UploadActions.loadUploadSuccess, (state, { upload }) => {
    console.log('yooo', upload);
    return uploadAdapter.setAll(upload as UploadEntity[], { ...state, loaded: true });
  }),
```

When I pass empty array to `UploadActions.loadUploadSuccess({upload: []});` it works just fine, but when I add the actual object I get the error.

From what I understand this is TypeError so something is wrong with types. I tried to use unknown, any, unknown[] and any[] in action but nothing helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a way to solve this issue. Its not a perfect solution, but it gets rid of the error.

https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/2404

The issue seems to be caused by immutability checks in ngrx. Once disabling them, the error goes away.

```
StoreModule.forRoot({},{
  runtimeChecks: {
    strictStateImmutability: false,
    strictActionImmutability: false,
  },
}),
```